# UIAlertContoller ios8 present in UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I have an app where when i tap on item in tableview on screen opens fullscreen photo presentation.

It is fullscreen so i add it directly to main window `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0]`  over my viewcontroller.

I have a menu for each image, it opens when i tap on UIBarButton that presents with image. i open my `UIActionSheet(self.imageActionSheet)` with code `[self.imageActionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sendButtonItem animated:YES];`

It works awesome on ios7, but on ios8 on iPad it doesn't opens.

I found that in ios8 ActionSheet is deprecated, and i should use UIAlertController.

I made a test alertcontroller for it

```
            UIAlertController * actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

            [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

            }]];

            UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController;
            if (popover)
            {
                UIView *buttonView = [sendButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"];
                popover.sourceView = buttonView;
                popover.sourceRect = buttonView.bounds;
                popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
            }
            UIWindow * wind = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];

            [wind.rootViewController presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It shows, but it shows under my fullscreen view that contained in `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0]` like subview. It contained at keyWindow because i need overlap all interface.

I found a way only present UIAlertController via ViewContoller, but all my viewControllers under my fullscreen view.

How i can show UIAlertController at UIWindow? or maybe from UIBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own UIWindow and put whatever you want in it, and it will be above everything including the status bar. I don't have a handy like to an example but you can find them. Look for examples of building your own UIAlertViewController. I used this at a previous job to build an alert that could have any number of items in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try like this..

AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        UIViewController* topVC = appDelegate.navC.topViewController;
        if (topVC.presentedViewController)
            topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
        [topVC presentViewController:alertViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: no, it still under my fullscreen view, i think it is because fullscreen view is on one level in hierarchy in keyWindow, but fullscreen was added later over the main VC.